# How to get latest frame in raspberry pi camera using OpenCV video capture in qt5?

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5

I am using opencv4.5.0 in raspberry pi with qt5 c++ by using OpenCV video capture to read a frame from the raspberry pi camera, it gives a buffer image but by using usb2 web camera (Logitech) works fine with the latest frame with the same code by setting buffer size 1 it gives the first 2 buffer frame images and the third image is the latest frame.
Please refer to the following code,

```
QScopedPointer<cv::VideoCapture> videoCapture_;

  videoCapture_.reset(new cv::VideoCapture(0));
  if (videoCapture_->isOpened())
  {
   videoCapture_->read(CaptureImage);
  }
```

Comment: tried some hack like call videoCapture_->read(CaptureImage); mutiple time in same function for single event to get latest frame but it take more then 200 ms

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-get-latest-frame-in-raspberrypi-camera-using-opencv-videocapture-in-c/6195